# Ros installtion getting stuck during build

Tags: c++, ros, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to installed ROS kinetic on raspberry pi 3 according to this [official page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi). Installation require to have 51 packages build. on "Roscpp" package build, whole pi3 gets hang(even with using -j2 option to reduce number of thread's). i tried 2-3 times but always same result, even i left for 1-2 days in same hang state by assuming that it will come out but build never completes. Is this is correct way to do it or there is any other way to do cross compilation and put package in pi3. Am i the only one who is facing this issue? (tried on 2 diff pi3).

Comment: Try adding some verbose flags so you see what it does. Also try using something like `top` to see if there are build processes which are actually doing something (as opposed to just waiting for who-knows-what).

Comment: Did you get this working by any chance? @hyde any idea on how to get past this?

Comment: Hi, it cant be compiled with raspberry pi because of processing and RAM capability. you can install 16.04 which and download precompiled packages from ubuntu repo. or else use better hardware

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my raspberry pi 2 model B but solved it by changing `-j4` to `-j2` option.

You can also add extra swap space by going to /etc/dphys-swapfile and changing the line:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
```

To something like this:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=1000
```