# Raspberry Pi crashes when I try to build the Catkin workspace [Robot Operating System]

Tags: build, raspbian, ros, raspberry-pi3, catkin

Currently I am trying to follow [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi#Setup_ROS_Repositories) guide here to start using the Robot Operating System (currently ROS Indigo). I am at the very final stage where I am trying to build the Catkin workspace using the command:

> sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo

*This command is from Section 3.3*

It works perfectly fine for the first 50 packages or so, but starts hanging when it reaches `rospack`. I am currently using the **Raspbian Jessie**, with the x11 desktop environment and trying to install the Desktop GUI version of ROS. I have followed every instruction till this point and am a bit baffled as to my next step.

[image]

*Here's a picture of the terminal up until when the raspberry pi freezes*

Is there a way to change the command mentioned above so that I can ignore `rospack` completely and deal with the issue once the dependencies have been resolved (the objective of *Section 3.3* of the guide)?

It can also be observed that the Raspberry Pi hits 100% processing and the screen blacks out after a little bit. The clock skew warning comes up on every package. I am not sure if this has something to do with this crash.

**Please ask me if you would like to get a picture of higher defintion for the terminal up until the freeze and crash**

---

**UPDATE**

*Here is a picture of what happens after a little while when I try and move the mouse :*

[image]

I'm going to try and run this on a different terminal altogether. THe current terminal is a Yakuake (Guake).

The very same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998007/ros-installtion-getting-stuck-during-build?rq=1), but without enough description or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to stop the Raspberry Pi from using up too much of the computational resources use the command:

> sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j1

The `-j1` option ensures this.

Comment: and so does -j2 and -j3 on my raspbian setup